# wget for image only in level2 and lower

Tags: unix, wget

I want to backup page including
  1)startpage,
  2)image on level2 that startpage linked to
  3)exclude link to html.

I try

```
-r -l 2 -A .jpg
```

but it didn't save my start page.

Please help if you have experience on this.

Answer (score 4):

The -r option will descend recursively ... with `-r -l 2` you are saying to descend the first two levels of the site ... If I understand you correctly, you don't want to start harvesting above level 2, is that right?